# How to Make a GUI program in separates files

Tags: java, file, user-interface

I want to make my GUI code in separates files. I'm reaching **1000 Line** in my program and this is stressful because all my code are in one file

Will to make long story short I'm working in a big program, so I will put an example to show you what I need.

First: This is an example code:

```
public class world extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textField;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    world frame = new world();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public world() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setBounds(0, 0, 427, 89);
        contentPane.add(textField);
        textField.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
        btnNewButton.setBounds(5, 137, 422, 111);
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                 String s = textField.getText();
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, s);
            }
        });
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton);
    }

}
```

Second: As you can see all the methods and everything in one file, and that not go for me.

Third: I want this code out of the parents class (main class), I don't know how,   is there a way to be inherited , or make a new class, or an interface class I need a way to my function or math outside the main method.

```
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                 String s = textField.getText();
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, s);
            }
        });
```

please give a written code if you are answering my question because I'm frustrated. I ask and ask, but I get completely different answer to what I need.

Comment: Dividing code into classes is one of the basic things you should learn, before attempting to create GUIs or anything. There's no simple way to "give you the codes", if you can't think of how to divide your code.

Comment: So what is the problem?, just go and divide it. Move business logic to other classes, and call them from GUI class. Make listener inner classes as simple and sort as possible....

Comment: You cannot split java classes into several files. As Kayaman suggested, you may want to look into things such as splitting your class into several other classes using inheritance or aggregation.

Maybe your main class is able to extend another one you make, or have a seperate class instance as a field parameter. That way you can do something like 
    this.MyUtilityClass.doSomething();

Comment: I think you should start with some simple OOP tutorial instead of diving directly in "big programs"

Comment: first of all thank you for your comments. Second, I have experiences in java and I know how to programmer a normal program. and I tried to inherit, make a new class and do an interface class for this code, and it worked the program. However When I click on the Button it's not given me any rustle, so that why I asked for a written code to see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @TheOneWhoPrograms - I think getting hung up on file vs. class is only going to confuse the issue, pretty sure he means them interchangably (technically wrong, but eh). It's pretty easy to split GUI instantiation across various classes, I find it's a great way to keep said projects readable (as Swing is a bit of a mess, and even other libraries can get lengthy). For example, you have a main interface where you instantiate all the main objects. Pass this into a controller, the controller calls the main().run() sequence, pull the JPanels from other widget classes or methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main class will look something like this

```
public class MyMainClass{ 
public static void main(String[] args){
MyClass myclass = new MyClass();
myclass.doSomething();
}
}
```

You other class would look something like this

```
public class MyClass{
public void doSomething()
{
//do something
}
}
}
```

This article is quite good to read as well http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=205

Answer (score 0):

put your main method in a seperate class file. the first thing the compiler reads is the main method. so if you put it in another class file your shouldn't be getting any problems unless you forget to import the class.

as for inheritance this is useful 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: first of all thank you for your comments. Second, I have experiences in java and I know how to programmer a normal program. and I tried to inherit, make a new class and do an interface class for this code, and it worked the program. However When I click on the Button it's not given me any rustle, so that why I asked for a written code to see what I'm doing wrong